# High CPU & Memory Spikes?

Tags: memory, server-load

I randomly get high spikes in CPU and Memory. I have deactivated nearly all plugins trying to find the culprit. I have been turning on a few at a time then waiting 30 minutes to see how if the server says it is okay. Which it always does. I didn't touch it for 3 hours tonight and when I returned I realized that my VPS randomly spiked at around 8PM and 9PM. But from 6PM-8PM no issues and from 930PM-1230AM no problems. It says my issue is with index.php.

This randomly started on the 26th. No new plugins, no script change, no difference at all.

How do I figure out what the issue is?

**More Info:**
I have two wordpress installations on my VPS. One of which is my main site that me and about 3 other people write on and the other is kind of like a picture site where you submit pictures and I approve them and they get posted. I have about 330 people on that site. The subdomain (picture site) is the one I am having issues with. It is not the theme index file that is causing the problem but the WP index file. Between the two websites I get about 500k views a month (more on the main site than the picture site)

**Server info:**

- Disk Space: 100gb
- Memory: 2GB
- Burst: 2GB
- Bandwidth: 1.5tb
- OS: CentOS 5.5 with Cpanel
- IP: 2
- Proccessor info:

  - 8 proccessors
  - GenuineIntel
  - Intel Core i7 CPU 870 @29.93 GHz
  - Speed: 2933.46 MHz
  - Cache: 8192kb

**Plugins (Currently activated)**

- Advanced Random Posts,
- bbpress integration,
- Custom Post Templates,
- GD Custom Posts and Taxonomies Tools,
- GD Star Rating,
- Gravity Forms,
- Members,
- Ultimate Category Excluder,
- Wordpress.com Stats,
- WP-Paginate,
- WP-PostRatings,
- WP-PostViews,

On that note, all of these and others were turned on and worked just fine. Then all of a sudden it went to heck. All plugins are updated and I have the most recent wordpress.

Comment: @Spewf Could you please edit your question and give some more details like your vps specs amount of traffic, etc..  Without knowing a little more it will be hard to give advice. index.php is the first file to load unless you mean your themes index.php.

Comment: Do you have some Transients API calls or cron jobs?

Comment: @Chris_0 I added more information
@kaiser How do I find out this info. I don't know much about cron jobs.

Comment: Give us a plugin list, some of them are memory killers. Like google sitemap xml - if you have a lot of posts.

Comment: @Marcin I just put an updated list of active plugins.

Comment: This is a "picture" site have you prevented hotlinking? How many posts/pages do you have? Does disabling the plugins prevent this at all, some of those are heavy.

Comment: Can you inspect the web server access logs for the time of the last spike? That might tell us whether the load is being generated by a particular client or type of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found what the problem was. WP-Postviews. I deactivated the plugin and removed all code from it on the site and now everything is running smoothly (at least for the last 3 hours).

Comment: So far the problem has not come back. I am pretty certain that was the issue.